# Xcode: How to build an static library with force_load another library (like tensorflow)?

Tags: ios, xcode, tensorflow

I'm trying to provide an IOS static library as a face SDK (named libA.a) using tensorflow. By tensorflow's instruction, I must link libTensorflow.a with force_load flag in my project. So I link libTensorflow.a with force_load flag in libA.a's project, and build a library(libA.a).

In a test, I create a sample app project (appB), and link my libA.a to use the face SDK. Compiling was success, but running result was bad for the force_load flag not work.

I try to solve this by link libTensorflow.a with force_load flag in my appB's project, it works fine but not in my desire (In my option, appB needn't be care of tensorflow, it just care of libA). How can I provide a "clean" library with force_load another library?